# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' on Eloquent create method

Tags: php, eloquent

I am currently trying to use Eloquent but I seem to have a problem when using its create method. Currently I am playing around with it and trying to get it working. When I run the create method I am given the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'field list''
```

My User model (User.php) is as follows:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class User extends Eloquent
{
    public $name;

    public $timestamps = array('created_at', 'updated_at');

    protected $fillable = array('username', 'name');
}
```

My home controller (home.php) is as follows:

```
<?php

class home extends Controller
{
    /**
    * Irrelevant method
    */
    public function index($name = '')
    {
        $this->view('home/index', array('name' => $user->name));
    }

    public function create($username = '', $name = '')
    {
        User::create(array('username' => $username, 'name' => $name));
    }
}
```

The index method is totally irrelevant to this matter. It is the create method. At this stage I am making sure it inserts records correctly. This is the URL I now type:

```
localhost:8888/mvc/public/home/create/someusername/Bob
```

This is when I am met with the error.

I don't know whether this matters but my composer.json file is as follows:

```
{
    "require": {
        "illuminate/database": "~4.2"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
          "app/model" 
        ]
    }
}
```

Anyone happen to know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have PDO installed on your server?

Comment: He does, otherwise he wouldn't get a PDOException.
Can you show us your migration? It seems as if your user table does not have a name field.

Comment: @SnakeFast This is my database table: https://pravi.us/Mvr

Comment: @user3481788 This error literally means that the column does not exist. Check your database name and make sure that you haven't made a typo or selected the wrong database by mistake.

Comment: Oh my, I just realised I was using the wrong database. Turns out it was that all along. Thank you